# Japanese equivalent to nonliteral "sounds like"

Tags: translation, expressions

I am trying to find phrases that mean the same thing as "sounds like" in English when used in the sense of

> It sounds like they are sincere, but they are trying to trick you.
> or
> That doesn't sound like the service you would usually get at a 5-star hotel.

Obviously this is not talking about the physical sounds being similar, so I wasn't sure if に聞こえる can be used. In the NINJAL corpus I found this sentence 「たいへん恐れおののいているように聞こえた。」, but it is clear that the speaker didn't hear them おののいている but heard something that made them think they were おののいている, so it's still talking about the physical sounds.

The odd thing is, I can see 聞こえる being used for the first of my two example sentences, but not the second.

Any help on possible phrases would be greatly appreciated (no need to focus on 聞こえる but I would like to know when it can be used like this).

Answer (score 3):

How about using そう(だ), よう(だ), or みたい(だ), as in:

> それは楽しそうね。/ おもしろそうですね。 That sounds like fun.
> 楽しかったようですね。/ 楽しかったみたいですね。 It sounds like you had a good time.

Comment: ok, but how would that be applied to "It sounds like they are sincere, but they are trying to trick you."

Comment: 「誠実そうだけど実はだまそうと…」とか「誠実そうでいて、実はだまそうと…」とか…「5つ星ホテルのサービスらしくない/っぽくないよね」とかですかね‥